# inline javascript works but external file does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

The problem is pretty straight forward.  The following code works perfectly when included inside script tags in my HTML document:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $('#contact-form').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        submitButtons: $('#contact-form-submit-button')
    });
}(window.jQuery));
```

However, once I try to load the script externally like this, it completely fails to do anything (I can confirm that the resource is getting properly served by the server.):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/nick/Documents/coding/sparestub/static_root/contact/js/contact.js"></script>
```

Does anyone have a clue what's going on here?  I'm think I'm going crazy.

EDIT: I figured it out. It turns out the element containing the #contact-form was being loaded asynchronously :(

Comment: Do you import it after jQuery?

Comment: I suggest you to share your Jsfiddle, or even better, show your code running here in a Stack Overflow Code Snippet: i.imgur.com/ga5xYYD.png

Comment: You don't seem to be on a particular web server; you're probably loading your page from the local file system. Move your page to a web server and everything should work fine. Or, simply put the script in the same folder as your page and load using `src="contact.js"`; it may work in some browsers.

Comment: I am importing this after jQuery.  As far as the webserver goes, you're right, I am loading the page from my filesystem. Why does that matter given this is a dev environment?  I'll try to get this working in Stack Overflow Code...

Comment: I just noticed that if I place a breakpoint in the code posted above, I actually hit it.  So the code is getting executed.  Does this mean that for some reason the bootstrapValidator library is failing?

Comment: What's your folder structure like? If my guess is correct, wouldn't `src="js/contact.js"` be the URL to use?

Comment: I am using Django's development web server.  I don't see how this is the issue.  The code is getting loaded by the browser just fine, evidenced by the breakpoint executing.

Comment: Do you have any kind of error in your console?

Comment: no console error at all. Does it matter if the src attribute has a relative path vs an absolute one?

Comment: I don't know much about django. But can you view the page source and confirm that the code is included after jQuery Core -- if it's loaded before jQuery that may be the cause of the failure.

Comment: The code is definitely included after jQuery core. If it wasn't, I think I would be getting a console error saying that $ is undefined.

Comment: I changed the code so that it serves directly from /static_root/.  Now the src element reads <script type="text/javascript" src="/static_root/contact/js/contact.js"></script>. This unfortunately did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file on your project file and you could do something like this,

~/Js/contact.js